# Loop task with counter using BPMN and Activiti?

Tags: activiti, bpmn

How can I create a gateway that will react to a counter using BPMN 2.0? If certain task was executed N times it should pass the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ***Multi-instance (for each)*** task type. See section 8.5.14. of Activiti (5.17) user [guide](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html). There is a ***completionCondition*** element.